# Form not minimizing properly

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to minimize a window to the taskbar? (i.e. not iconify)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228966/how-to-minimize-a-window-to-the-taskbar-i-e-not-iconify)

I want to show some form before showing the main form in my app, I do:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  with TForm2.Create(Application) do
    try
      ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

It's working properly but when I minimizing first form (TForm2) it's doing something like this (not minimizing to taskbar):

[image: Minimize problem]

What's wrong?

Comment: @NGLN I can't hide Application.Handle from the taskbar with `ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);`

Comment: @NGLN Yikes, me must read more, works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to `Hide` it before you Free first. I don't know but if your first form is an authentication form maybe you could also use `ModalResult` to be sure that the user's response was ok.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question isn't about hiding or freeing the form. Before the form is freed -- while it's still visible and the user is interacting with it -- it apparently doesn't minimize properly, as shown in the picture.

Comment: You're right, this could be related to the kind of form he's using, SDI or MDI?